# Equivalence of boundedness definitions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to, for the purpose of understanding Rudin's definition of boundedness in a metric space, reconcile this with the definition of boundedness in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I'm accustomed to. Here are the two definitions. Rudin's definition is for a general metric space, but I'm going to limit this to just $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the moment.

**(1) My "Intuitive" Definition**

> In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, we say $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that for every $x \in E$, we have $|x| < M$.

**(2) Rudin's definition (Definition 2.18(i))**

> $E$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $p \in X$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $p \in E$.

These definitions appear very different to me, and the second is a bit unintuitive. Here is my attempt to reconcile them. If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded by the first definition, then it is also bounded by the second definition by taking $p$ to be the zero vector. The other direction I'm less sure on. Let's saying that $E$ is bounded by definition (2). Then there exists $M$ (I might as well assume $M > 0$, since $d$ is non-negative anyway) and $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $d(p,x) = |p-x| < M$. Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I can attempt to bound $|x|$ by the triangle inequality:
$$
|x| = |(x-p) + p| \leq |x-p| + |p| < M + |p|.
$$
I think, since this $p$ is fixed at the moment, I can choose a bound that depends on $p$. So I can set $N = M + |p|$. Then, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $|x| < N$.

How does this look? If there is a tighter bound that I'm missing, I'd appreciate some help with finding it. Also, any intuition on why this second definition makes sense would be very helpful.

Comment: Why is the origin special in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any other (fixed)) point would suffice, but since the origin is sort of special, might as well use that :-).

Comment: The second definition is basically the same as your definition, as you observed, when you set $p=0$ (except for a typo, it should be "for all $q\in E$" at the end). Now, think about the following: what would be your intuitive definition in a metric space that doesn't have an algebraic structure (so there's no such thing as $0$)? I would be surprised if you don't come out with the second definition.

Comment: Also, show that being bounded in a metric space is not dependent on the specific $p$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm having some trouble showing this. I think one way to show this it to  argue that if $p$ satisfies the definition, then $p-q$ must also for any $q \in X$. Is that the idea?

Comment: Suppose it is bounded with respect to $p$. Pick any other point $q$. Then $d(x,q) \le d(x,p)+d(p,q)$. Hence $p$ bounded implies $q$ bounded. Similar reasoning shows that $q$ bounded implies $p$ bounded. (The '$M$'s will be different, of course.)

Comment: Your proof that $2\implies1$ is fine. In an arbitrary metric space you can adapt it, replacing 0 with q and |p| with d(p,q).